# How to pass large and complex xml body in rest assured framework using java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, rest-assured

I have worked on small xml body request less than 20 lines and I created key value pairs for it in java.
But I have to use acord xml as payload request to get a response which is more than 250 lines. I tried using form-data to provide as .xml file which is not working. 
contentType is xml format and response is received in xml format.

Can somebody please guide me in the right direction, on how to achieve this if coded in a framework?

```
@Test
public void xmlPostRequest_Test() {

    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8006";

    String requestBody = "<client>\r\n" +
        "    <clientNo>100</clientNo>\r\n" +
        "    <name>Tom Cruise</name>\r\n" +
        "    <ssn>124-542-5555</ssn>\r\n" +
        "</client>";

    Response response = null;

    response = given().
    contentType(ContentType.XML)
        .accept(ContentType.XML)
        .body(requestBody)
        .when()
        .post("/addClient");

    System.out.println("Post Response :" + response.asString());
    System.out.println("Status Code :" + response.getStatusCode());
    System.out.println("Does Reponse contains '100 Tom Cruise 124-542-5555'? :" + response.asString().contains("100 Tom Cruise 124-542-5555"));
}
```

Comment: can you show the code? can you tell what framework are you using?

Comment: Its going to be TestNG using restassured jars in java. Above is the sample code, but what if the xml body is more than 250 lines. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: my first suggestion will be to read the xml body from a file and you can easly assign it to requestBody.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   public static Response validateXmlResponse() throws IOException {
         // Navigate to xml file path attached in project
         String FilePath = "c\downloads\filepath;
         String XMLBodyToPost = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(FilePath)));

         // Call the baseUrl to test the request
         RestAssured.baseURI = TestURL;

         // Getting a reponse for submitted POST request
         Response res = given().auth().basic(userName, password).body(XMLBodyToPost).
                      when().post()
                      .then()
                .statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.HTML).extract().response();
         String response = res.asString();
         // System.out.println("Returning response as string format:" + " " + response);

         return res;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a file to pass the xml payload .

Please see the below code and provide a feedback . It's been tested and working .

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.when;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.filter.session.SessionFilter;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

public class XmlExample {
    //@Test
    public void postComplexXML() throws IOException {
        String FilePath="path\\to\\xml.xml";
        String XMLBodyToPost=generateStringFromResource(FilePath);
        RestAssured.baseURI="http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/IND/UP";
    Response res=   given().queryParam("key", "value").body(XMLBodyToPost).when().post().then().statusCode(201).and().
        contentType(ContentType.XML).extract().response();
    //Pass the RrstAssured Response to convert to XML
    XmlPath x=rawToXML(res);
    //Get country value from response
    String country=x.get("RestResponse.result.country");
    int size=x.get("result()");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It worked. I was able to pass the file path as payload in body